# "systemctl: command not found" with vagrant on fresh CentOS 6.5 install

Tags: centos, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm creating new vagrant box that uses virtualbox image of CentOS 6.5 that I installed. Inside everything looks fine, but from outside **I can't access 80 port**.

When I edited my Vagrantfile and added fixed IP:
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10"
And I ran vagrant up, I got "systemctl command not found".

I think this it tries to setup network interface, but fails because it uses systemctl which, I assume is not available in this version or distribution. 
**Is there a way to add it, or configure IP/network interface manually?** So that vagrant connects to it?

```
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

systemctl stop etcd
ifconfig 10.10.10.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
mv /tmp/etcd-cluster.service /media/state/units/
systemctl restart local-enable.service

# Restart default etcd
systemctl start etcd


Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

bash: line 3: systemctl: command not found
SIOCSIFNETMASK: No such device
SIOCGIFADDR: No such device
SIOCSIFBROADCAST: No such device
mv: cannot move `/tmp/etcd-cluster.service' to `/media/state/units/': No such file or directory
bash: line 6: systemctl: command not found
bash: line 9: systemctl: command not found
```

Comment: `systemctl` is part of new centos7 its not available on centos65 - are you running this command from provision script or how ?

Comment: no, this is generated by vagrant when I change Vagrantfile and add fixed IP:
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10"

Comment: sytemd is not the init system for Centos6 so `systemctl` cannot be made available.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the cause, but the culprit could have been **SELinux**. Maybe it blocked connections or permissions. Got it working later:

```
setenforce Permissive
nano /etc/sysconfig/selinux
#setting SELINUX=disabled
```